# How to pass a whole dojox.grid.DataGrid store(items json data) to servlet?

Tags: json, datagrid, dojo

I have a button on page - when clicked, it passes all the data to the servlet that could update each row data.  My question is how to pass the whole store to the servlet as json data? Is there any easy way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code I wrote to get the store to an object.  Then it can be converted to JSON using `dojo.toJson(obj);`.  I learned about this from the [dojotoolkit website](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore.html) originally.  (Give credit where credit is due).  I realize this code is huge and nasty.  When I looked for a better way about a year back I could not find one.

```
JsonHelper.storeToObject = function(store) {
    var object = [];
    var index = -1;
    store.fetch({
        onItem : function(item, request) {
            object[++index] = JsonHelper.itemToObject(store, item);
        }
    });
    return object;
};

JsonHelper.itemToObject = function(store, item) {
    // store:
    // The datastore the item came from.
    // item:
    // The item in question.
    var obj = {};
    if (item && store) {
        // Determine the attributes we need to process.
        var attributes = store.getAttributes(item);
        if (attributes && attributes.length > 0) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
                var values = store.getValues(item, attributes[i]);
                if (values) {
                    // Handle multivalued and single-valued attributes.
                    if (values.length > 1) {
                        var j;
                        obj[attributes[i]] = [];
                        for (j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                            var value = values[j];
                            // Check that the value isn't another item. If
                            // it is, process it as an item.
                            if (store.isItem(value)) {
                                obj[attributes[i]].push(itemToObject(store,
                                        value));
                            } else {
                                obj[attributes[i]].push(value);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (store.isItem(values[0])) {
                            obj[attributes[i]] = itemToObject(store,
                                    values[0]);
                        } else {
                            obj[attributes[i]] = values[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

Comment: You're welcome @JerryCai!  I wish the code was smaller. Oh well!