# Reading data from a CSVStore in Dojo

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Let's say I have a `CSVStore` connected to an editable grid:

```
var csvStore = dojox.data.CsvStore({data: csvData, separator: ","});

this._grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
  id: gridId,
  store: csvStore,
  structure: layout,

  ...
});
```

How can I retrieve the modified data stored in the `CSVStore` in CSV format? I'm looking for something like this:

```
var modifiedCSVData = csvStore.getCSVData();
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but I answered a similar question the other day.  Someone was trying to **[get the data from a dojo store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650541/how-to-pass-a-whole-dojox-grid-datagrid-storeitems-json-data-to-servlet/15650691#15650691)**.  In this case it was in `JSON`, not `CSV`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that's the only way to do it. I wrote a function that grabbed the data from the store and then used `Array.join` to convert it back to CSV format. It's a shame Dojo doesn't support this obvious use case. If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question the other day. Someone was trying to **[get the data from a dojo store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650541/how-to-pass-a-whole-dojox-grid-datagrid-storeitems-json-data-to-servlet/15650691#15650691)**. In this case it was in `JSON`, not `CSV`.  You could use the same technique to build an object.  Then instead of converting it to JSON, convert it to CSV using `Array.join` as you said in your comment.  Glad I could help, and I totally agree; this is a missing use case of the dojo store.